# Can not get a styled anchor tag to display the proper height and width attributes for a simulated button in email on Outlook 2013 for Windows

Tags: html-email

My code does work properly in Outlook 15.33 for Mac. Buttons take the height and width of the linked text in the Windows version of Outlook. I have tried setting the buttons as  tags and  tags, but I have the same formatting issues on the Windows version of Outlook.

```
<table class="fullwidth260" border="0" width="215" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5" align="left">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td valign="middle">
<a class="quickLinks" href="http://www.mba.org" style="display: flex; text-align: center; padding: 10px 20px 10px 20px; color: #496f8d; font-family: Arial, san-serif; size: 10pt; line-height: 1.2; border: 1px solid #c8d3dc; background-color: #e3e9ed; text-decoration: none; height: 60px; width: 160px; justify-content: center; flex-direction: column;">STATE RELATIONS ONLINE COMMUNITY</a>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your designing for email, not for the Web. Outlook non-Mac does not fully support the CSS attributes flex or padding.

Outlook is a major pain to get buttons to display correctly. I'd give you more advice, but you didn't post your existing code which makes it hard to make suggestions on how to offer better advice to fix your issues.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Give this method a try. I found it to work on all email clients that i know off. You will need to change the background color of the td, background color of the anchor tag, stroke color and the width of the button.

```html
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="margin:0 auto;">
                <tr>
                  <td align="center" bgcolor="#87be45" width="150" style="-moz-border-radius: 4px; -webkit-border-radius: 4px; border-radius: 4px;">
                    <a href="http://www.example.com" style="padding: 10px;width:150px;display: block;text-decoration: none;border:0;text-align: center;font-weight: bold;font-size: 15px;font-family: sans-serif;color: #ffffff;background: #87be45;border: 1px solid #87be45;-moz-border-radius: 4px; -webkit-border-radius: 4px; border-radius: 4px;line-height:17px;" class="button_link">
                      Get Started!
                    </a>
                  </td>
                </tr>
              </table>
```

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Your method led me to what I needed. I had to put the in-line styling on the <td> tag. When I tried to apply the styling to the <a> tag it applied it twice when the text in the buttons formatted as two lines. This is the final result: [link] (https://mba-pc.informz.net/informzdataservice/onlineversion/ind/bWFpbGluZ2luc3RhbmNlaWQ9NjIzNzcyNCZzdWJzY3JpYmVyaWQ9NzgxNTM2NzU3)

Comment: If this solved the question in your original post then accept the answer please. Also a 1 up would be nice ;-)